# Django products app with variable depth category hierarchy and arbitrary attributes per category

Tags: django, satchmo, commerce

I'm starting work on a product catalog built in Django for a client that needs:

1- **a variable depth category / subcategory structure**, so the tree could look like:

cat 1 > subcat 1 > subsubcat 1 > product 1

cat 2 > subcat 2 > product 2

cat 3 > product 3

2- **the products of any category or subcategory can have an arbitrary set of attributes**,
so for example the products under 'plotter' could have 'speed', 'size' and 'paper type' attributes, whereas the products under 'cad software' could have 'version', 'license type' and   'number of seats'.

3- **An easy to use backend, hopefully allowing drag and drop ordering and categorizing of products**.

So, I've looked into Satchmo and it has 'product attributes', which looks similar to what I need, and Mezzanine which doesn't have a Product model but otherwise seems fairly hackable and has a nice backend.

I haven't used either project, and am wondering if they're overkill (I don't need shopping cart, payment, etc, or the full blog thing of Mezzanine), perhaps there's a simpler application or aplications for the specific needs I have?

Comment: yes, I could. Before I do that, I want to see if an existing project already has something close to what I need as a starting point, so as to save time and use something already tested and optimized.

Comment: Good point. I am learning Django and always lean towards rolling my own to get an idea of how it works quicker. But Sorry I can't be more helpful

Comment: I can't help you exactly, but, I can tell you we've been rolling our own stand-alone product catalog app (don't have a release yet) and we're using django-mptt for the category structure. It's pretty easy to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Satchmo has all the functionality that you are looking for, In fact it has lot more functionality than what you are looking for. I recommend Satchmo